# Generate an initialization vector without a good source of randomness

Tags: c, random, cryptography, initialization-vector

For a password storing plugin (written in C) for Rockbox I need to generate initialization vectors.

The problem is that I don't have a good source of randomness. The Rockbox-supplied random() is not a cryptographic RNG. And I've got hardly any sources of randomness I can access (no mouse movements, ... on an IPod running Rockbox).

The key is currently derived via PBKDF2 from a user-supplied password and a salt (which is a constant prefix + some data from random()). I think the pseudo-random data should be good enough for a salt with 10000 iterations of PBKDF2.

However, where do I take my initialization vector from? Is it OK if I take some semi-random data (time + random()) and SHA that, say, 10000 times? Should I take arc4random with a seed taken from random()?

Do I even need an IV if I effectively never use the same key twice (the salt is recomputed every time the stored data is changed)? What's the best way to deal with situations like these?

Edit:
Just a single user (me, owning the IPod), encryption algorithm: AES-CBC 256 bit.
The file just stores a site/account/password list for various websites. It is rarely modified (whenever I create a new account on a website), when that happens a new salt and a new IV is generated.

Comment: Don't SHA 10000 times, SHA just once. Iterating the hash function wasn't the intended design and might make the output "less random".

Comment: You'd better explain in more detail what you're doing. For example, an IV for which algorithm? Different algorithms have different IV requirements.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention those details.

Comment: @Thomas:  Users of PBKDF2, which utilizes many hash iterations, would disagree with you.  E.g., http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-3741

Comment: @indiv: That's how I came up with the 10000xSHA1 idea in the first place, however it's more complicated. PBKDF2 explicitely addresses that problem by XOR'in together all the intermediate hashes; from RFC2898, section 5.2 (PBKDF2):
"""Note. The construction of the function F follows a "belt-and-suspenders" approach. The iterates U_i are computed recursively to remove a degree of parallelism from an opponent; they are exclusive-ored together to reduce concerns about the recursion degenerating into a small set of values."""

Comment: @Christian, @Thomas:  Huh, interesting.  I guess I stand corrected, and will look into it more.

Comment: @Thomas Iterating a secure hash won't make the output 'less random' - if it did, that'd be an obvious and exploitable weakness in the hash function. You're right that it's pointless in this case.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: A hash function maps _any_ byte string into a byte string of fixed length. There's only a finite number of these, say N (e.g. N = 2^256). Unless the hash function is injective on this set, then N values get mapped to _less_ than N values, making some outcomes impossible, hence making the result more predictable. I don't think any hash function in common usage is known to be injective, so this is a real problem.

Comment: @Thomas While trivially true, this is irrelevant, just like the fact that multiple longer strings must hash to the same hash value. Secure hash functions are designed such that it's impractical to find collisions, so using them iteratively doesn't provide an exploitable weakness. In fact, iterative hashing is a valid primitive used in several contexts, including PBKDF2. If you believe otherwise, please provide an example of an attack that exploits iterative hashing!

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Not a clue, you're probably right. But could you explain to this poor crypto noob why we would iterate SHA1 in the situation above, instead of applying it only once?

Comment: @Thomas: multiple iterations are meant to make the operation slow. This makes things harder for both the normal user, and the attacker who is trying to "guess" the password. But the normal user has only one password to convert into a key, whereas the attacker wants to try thousands per second, so iterations are usually considered to be a good thing. As for space reduction, theory has it that it will not go below sqrt(N), and that's still high enough for proper security.

Comment: @Thomas In the case of the IV, I don't believe there is much or any value in iterating. In the case of key derivation functions, as @Thomas Pornin illustrates, it's designed to slow things down to make attacks harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, with CBC, the IV **MUST** be random and uniform. "Non-repeating" is not sufficient. To be more precise, the whole point of CBC is to avoid the situation where the same data block is fed twice to the underlying block cipher. Hence, the condition is that if you encrypt two messages with the same key, then the *difference* of the two IV must be uniformly random. With a 128-bit block cipher such as the AES, the probability that the same block is obtained twice is sufficiently low as to be neglected -- as long as the IV is randomly chosen with uniform probability over the whole space of 128-bit values. Any structure in the IV selection (such as reusing the same IV, using a counter, or a low-quality random generator) increases that probability, because you are encrypting data which has itself a lot of structure.

There is a bright side to that: if you *never* use the same key twice, then you can tolerate a fixed IV. But that is a strong "never".

"Non-repeating IV" is not a good enough property with CBC. However, there are some encryption modes which can use non-repeating IV. In particular, have a look at [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) and [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). The trick here is that those mode use the provided IV in a custom PRNG which uses the encryption key; this transform the non-repeating IV (e.g. a counter, or a "random value" of low quality) into something which, from a cryptographic point of view, looks random enough. Do not try to build your own PRNG ! These things are subtle and there is no sure way to test the quality of the result.

Answer (score 2):

The IV does not need to be random, it just needs to be unique for a given pair of key and data (assuming we are talking about an IV for CBC).

So random() should be okay for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

GREAT NEWS! The initialization vector doesn't need to be random, it just needs to be different for every encryption. So you can use the user's name as the salt. If you use both the user's name and the time then an attacker won't be able to detect password reuse.

Comment: So to sum it up, for secure AES-CBC encryption of data with a user-chosen password, neiter salt nor IV have to be cryptographically random, any random data from some PRNG suffices; right?

Comment: Any data suffices provided that it's always different. And you need to preserve the salt or the IV through to the output. But you don't need both a salt and an IV; they are really the same thing.